# nuxtjs cannot display dynamic url on production

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxjs to build my project and I create a page which displays place information dynamically.

[image]

when I run `npm run dev` and test on http://localhost:3000/place/66bb50b7a5 is work well.

but after I run `npm run generate`, I get the dist folder, I put in on MAMAP and try to run http://mysite:7074/place/66bb50b7a5, it shows 404 page not found.

My dist folder is like this

[image]

please tell me what wrong on my code and what I should do.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you every find a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 9):

You have to config your web server to response `index.html` when receive requests like `/place/66bb50b7a5`

[vue-router doc](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) have example configurations for Apache, nginx, IIS...

For MAMP (apache):

1. create an file name `.htaccess` in your MAMP `htdocs` folder
2. paste apache configuration from vue-router doc

`.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI, this should do the job, have you tried this or not?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and I've solved it.

my case in apache:

1. create `.htaccess` file in the same folder as index.html
2. copy-paste the following script, and all works charmly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Rew/riteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Previously I found this script on [github](https://gist.github.com/mariojankovic/e39cce4fed0db39e21e29a1585fd2155)