# NuxtJS dynamic URLs for static site

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, nuxt.js

How can I allow for dynamic URLs on a static Nuxt.js application? I have some dynamic routes like this.

```
/user/_user
/order-confirmation/_key
/some-route/_key/with/additional/_slug
```

I generate most of the routes on build time, but some IDs will exist after creating the app. I believe I could use .htaccess somehow to allow for this, but so far, I haven't been able to get it working. I have tried with this: [nuxtjs cannot display dynamic url on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47384751/nuxtjs-cannot-display-dynamic-url-on-production) - but that doesn't seem to work either.

I can't believe there isn't more information on this, must be a pretty regular usecase.

Comment: I assume by "dynamic URL" you mean one that does not map directly to a filesystem path, so requires a _front-controller_ to route the request to the script that actually handles the request (as in the question you link to)? If so then we need to know more about your system... the file system structure, document root of the server and the script that is to handle the request. (Otherwise, the question you link to would seem to contain the "generalised" answer - which is likely to need modifying depending on your requirements.)

Comment: It should be possible with a normal `.htaccess`

Comment: Walter, have a look at https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/7051#issuecomment-597610691. But please don't involve Jessie

Comment: Yes, this may be possible with `.htaccess`. However, we need more information to be able to answer - as requested in my comment above. You say that the solution in the linked question "doesn't seem to work" - what do you mean by this? Does it do _anything_? What version of Apache are you one? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled? Is mod_rewrite installed? What exactly do you want `.htaccess` to do? Route all requests that would otherwise trigger a 404 to a script that handles the request? Or route only specific URL patterns?